# fread a file that is changing

Tags: php, file, file-io, buffer, fread

Provided the following example code:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("/tmp/test_file/sometestfile", "r");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $contents = fread($handle, 10);
    print $contents;
    sleep(1);
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

If sometestfile, which is a txt file in my case, changes during the read loop, why is the php program continuing to read from the old file? 
Say it is full of 1's and I cat sometestfile_new over it which is full of 2's.
I am running this on Linux, is this inode related? 
If rewind() is added after each loop, the new file will be read instead, after the overwrite point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
resource fopen ( string $filename , string $mode [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )
```

`fopen()` binds a named resource, specified by `filename`, to a stream.

the `fopen()` as soon as it's called it "caches" the file and will output in the method you mention, example is your `$contents = fread($handle, 10);`

You can delete the file and it will still read that resource until it finishes the file `!feof($handle)`

You cannot do anything else with `fopen()`, you just can't reread the source and continue to print it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you know of a documented resource that says fopen will cache the file? Like I said using rewind() will turn on the read process to the new file.

This might be related to this as well: stream_set_read_buffer(), but the function is introduced only from 5.3.3

Comment: it does not have to be documented. As soon as a file is read by fopen, assuming ``$file = fopen('file.txt', 'a')``, that variable will have the contents of ``file.txt`` so it doesn't matter what happens with it after ``fopen()`` occurs that variable will have the contents until the script is parsed.